# How to save w3schools example as an AngularJs component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-components

I am creating a simple app in `AngularJS` and I am trying to build [form steps wizard](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps) but JS is not getting applied.

I have copy pasted all the code from w3schools editor to the component.html file

getting the following output

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/po4b4.png)

Comment: Code on the site w3school not written in Angularjs, but in pure JS, that's why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way you can reuse this code is to take advantage of HTML `<iframe>`. Assuming that you saved all code from w3c site to file `my_downloaded_code.html` your iframe will look like

```
<iframe src = "path/to/file/my_downloaded_file.html" width="350px" height="600px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Attributes width, height etc. are not mandatory of course, but I have chosen them for exactly that case.

What's more **the form is sent to action_page.php** after confirmation, so You have to create such a file in appropriate localization (the same as the localization of `my_downloaded_code.html`).

**However**, if you like to make a AngularJS component containing that code it won't be very easy because as @Tomas commented

> Code on the site w3school not written in Angularjs, but in pure JS...

but it is possible of course :) .

What have to be done?

1. Functions have to be moved to component controller.
2. Functions and variables in controller have to be visible in `template`, thus we must assign them to `$scope`.
3. `on-click` has to be changed to `ng-click`
4. Content of `<style>` tag has to be moved to `.css` file
5. You must create your action_page.php

I have made [plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/HaVZKcpqsYJ0GECs?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1&preview) with such working component for You.